# Android emulator after booting does not launch flutter app

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I have a flutter project which I am developing in vs code. Sometimes I have a very hard time launching my app on the emulator, it just keeps saying the below [image]

I do see the emulator booted up but it just does not launch my app.

This has been frustrating for some time.

Has anybody experienced this?